# How do you connect flutter and azure for user sign in

Tags: flutter, firebase, azure

I have a directory in Azure that already has a set of users. I am creating an app using flutter and want to use firebase authentication. How can I link the users I already have in azure with firebase?

When I use the sign up page in my app, users are added in firebase, but not azure. No users from azure can sign in to my app either (account not found).

Answer (score 0):

Use the federated identity `MicrosoftAuthProvider` to authenticate users.

```
final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
```

See [Federated identity & social sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#microsoft) for details.